# Multiple links to same page google analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

So in google analytics I am seeing two links for every post I have on my wordpress site.  See: https://www.screencast.com/t/JVoudis1eK8P

All the duplicate links are the same except for /404/ at the beginning.  I checked my database and don't see these links.  They do link to the correct page and don't display the /404/ in the url toolbar when clicked.

I inherited this site so I didn't set it up.  Has anyone ever seen this? Is a plugin doing this? (We use yoast).

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer if you could share the url. But my bet is on a misconfigured filter in the Google Analytics view settings.

Comment: blog.omnipress.com

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion isn't Google Analytics, but something on your site isn't right. Load up an Inspect session in your browser such as Google Chrome, and then go to the Network tab, and watch each request. You'll look for the "status" column for anything that's not a 200. I'd bet something like a JS, CSS, or image isn't loading, and your site is redirecting each 404 request to a page and passing the referring URL to it.

Comment: http://blog.omnipress.com/2011/08/five-must-have-features-of-inventory-management-systems-for-educational-publications/

I inspected this page it has a few not 200 statuses but no 404.